# Repeat count for UIView block-based animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I've looked at the methods for block based animation and noticed there is no equivalent parameter or option for `[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:]`.

What's the simplest way to repeat an animation a fixed number of times? Do you, for instance, chain them using the completion block?

Comment: Didn't get it. There is a setAnimationRepeatCount method in UIView. What is your problem actually?

Comment: See the methods in UIView's documentation listed under 'Animating Views with Blocks'. They don't mix with the older 'Animating Views' methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a completion callback - re-initiate the animation in it - and keep track of the counter yourself.

Comment: That was my guess too. I just hoped there is a simpler solution.

Comment: For a use-case where text should blink 3 times ... I didn't have to keep track of the counter, I just had to set `setAnimationRepeatCount` before the animations in the `animations` block, in order for it to be effective: https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/6152975

Answer (score 23):

I just asked a similar question and then I read the 2010-11-15 release of the View Programming Guide for iOS. Page 64 caught my attention.

In the animation block, one can still use the `[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:]`. I thought that I could/should not. So my ability to read Apple doc needs to improve.

So perhaps this would solve your (and my need). I'm trying it later today

Comment: link to the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW38

Answer (score 5):

As @PommeOuest mentioned. You can still user [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:] inside the animation block. I just tried in my project and it works well.

I'm using XCode4 and iOS5.